# NPM packages error out because of webpack

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, netlify

I've created a Netlify site that is running a create-react-app project and using Netlify's lambda functions feature. However, when I try to use packages such as mysql or mysql2 I get webpack errors. These have been documented on the github issues for each library, but I don't have access to the webpack config to add a "quick fix". I can't imagine that i'm the only one running into this issue, but what are my options?

Is there a way to prevent webpack from touching my server-side packages? Is this happening because of how Netlify stores both client and server-side code in the same root directory?

I've exhausted just about every option I could think of over the last couple of days. Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's more than one way to deploy Netlify's lambda functions. Keep in mind, lambda functions are just node modules that export a handler. After the build, Netlify will use the functions value under build in `netlify.toml` to get the directory to deploy for your functions.

#### Common ways to create these functions

- Using the Netlify Cli (`netlify-cli`) from a terminal.
- During CI/CD, use `netlify-lambda` cli to bundle the function(s) from a source
  location to a folder specified in your `netlify.toml` under
  `build.functions`. This allows you to prepare them for deployment
  with a basic webpack/Babel setup targeting modern Javascript.
- Don't pre-process, but just put your function(s) directly into the directory specified in your `netlify.toml` under `build.functions`.

The last option is the one you probably want to use in this case.

#### Setting up your functions for deployment using the last option

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  functions = "functions"
```

`/functions/somefunction/somefunction.js`

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
.
.
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
 .
 .
}
.
```

Create a `/functions/somefunction/package.json` file with the dependencies needed. In this case, you would use `mysql`, and any others you require in your functions. Should also use the `package-lock.json` file to lock in the version you want.

In your root package.json, setup a pre-process script command to `cd ./functions/somefunction && npm install` to install the dependencies prior to any build commands. This will bundle up the dependencies into `/functions/somefunction/node_modules` and will be ready for netlify to deploy along with your `somefunction` function. The pre-process command will allow you to leave the node_modules out of your git repository.

[Here is an example of a `create-react-app` with netlify functions](https://github.com/talves/netlify-functions-cra-example) that uses the method described above where the functions are not bundled using webpack or `netlify-lambda`, but have dependencies that are pre installled during the build prior to deploy. This example uses a sub-directory for the `joke-async` function.

Comment: Does this prevent webpack from touching these npm packages though? That's what's causing my issues in using the mysql library. I've tried what you have above on netlify dev but I am getting the same errors.

Comment: It should. It is hard to say why your setup would still be getting those errors without seeing how everything is setup. Also `netlify dev` may be trying to also transpile the code. I would have to test that case.

Comment: Note: just tested the above using a create-react-app and `netlify dev` and it worked without errors with `const mysql = require('mysql')` in my function and using a bundled package.json in the functions directory.

Comment: In `netlify.toml` I am pointing to `./lambda' to build my functions and the `build/serve` functions point to `functions` as the source. If I try to make them the same I get a Netlify dev error saying that they must be different.

Comment: Also, i've placed the mysql code in another file while I am importing into my function with `import DB from './core/DB'` could that be the issue?

Comment: I thought you couldn't use the function build workflow, because `mysql` is a node module and you are getting a build error? If that is the case, that is the solution I was proposing above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195211/discussion-between-talves-and-matt-butler).